Wifi Connected without Internet, never rechecks the connection
I'm in a rural area with a spotty internet connection. Each time when connection worsens for a few seconds (pings to google drop), my android shows me that I'm "Connected without Internet", and I have an exclamation mark over my WiFi status indicator.
The problem is that when the connection is restored within seconds, the phone never actually checks for that, or does it on an unreasonably long time interval of several minutes (where seconds would have been enough), and stays without connection. As in apps don't have internet access.
Is there anything I can do to change this interval? The only thing I can do so far is turn off / turn on WiFi to force recheck, but doing it every couple of minutes is extremely tedious.
Samsung S10e, Android 11, ROOT.

I assume you have a stable WiFi connection but somewhere afterwards the connection becomes unstable. Detecting a lost connection in such a system is easy but detecting the opposite is difficult as you can only actively probe the connection. But that would require to periodically send data which costs battery so Android doesn't do it often. I am not sure if you can configure the frequency of the network checks.
